# I'm having trouble rendering a component to the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a complete novice when it comes to React. I opted to include the React & ReactDOM CDN in the file.

I'm having trouble rendering this component.

```
<script type="text/babel">

        function Header(){

        return(
            <div>
            <p>Blog</p>
            </div>
            );

        }

    ReactDOM.render(<Header />);
</script>
```

Comment: ReactDOM needs a container to render to as the second parameter. https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering react inside the DOM with a script Tag.

ReactDOM.render is using 2 parameters, The main component (App) and the location (mostly a div tag inside the body with an ID of "root".

So the right way to render Your first React App.js will be:

```html
const App = () => {
  return <div>Hello World</div>
}
```

Each React Component must start with a capital letter.

To render this App.js component you'll create an index.js component with ReactDOM.render() such as:

```html
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

The HTML Would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You do not add any JS inside the DOM or any HTML tags. you are doing everything with React JSX.

So if you want a header You are creating a Header component and wrap it inside the App.js component.

I really recommend you to learn more about React because if you are not sure what you're doing, it would be a mess and your app will have a very low performance.

Check out React documents [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#learn-react).